# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Installed Android Studio and flutter sdk (downloaded zip and unzip) on my mac. I created new flutter simple project on android studio app and ran it. Then, I got following error message.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM5RT.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre

ln -s ../jre jdk

ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk

flutter doctor -v
```

I ran above commands in terminal and it is solved.